# Specialize a class template within a class template?

Tags: c++, templates, generics

The definition below is failing... I'm thinking it has something to do with specializing a class template (Vector) within another class template (Graph). Thanks!

```
this is the part giving me trouble (defined in Graph below) -> 
std::map<KeyType, Vertex<KeyType, ObjectType> > vertexes;

template <class KeyType, class ObjectType>
class Vertex
{
private:
    KeyType key;
    const ObjectType* object;
public:
    Vertex(const KeyType& key, const ObjectType& object);
    const KeyType getKey();
};

template <class KeyType, class ObjectType> 
class Graph
{
private:
    std::map<KeyType, Vertex<KeyType, ObjectType> > vertexes;
public:
    const Vertex<KeyType, ObjectType>& createVertex(const KeyType& key, const ObjectType& object);
};

template <class KeyType, class ObjectType>
const Vertex<KeyType, ObjectType>& Graph<KeyType, ObjectType>::createVertex(const KeyType& key, const ObjectType& object)
{
    Vertex<KeyType, ObjectType> *vertex = new Vertex<KeyType, ObjectType>(key, object);
    vertexes.insert(pair<KeyType, Vertex<KeyType, ObjectType> >(vertex.getKey(), vertex));
    return *vertex;
};
```

Visual Studio 10 reports:

Error   1   error C2228: left of '.getKey' must have class/struct/union c:\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\socialnetwork\socialnetwork\graph.h    46  1   SocialNetwork

The line mentioned in the error corresponds to the the vertexes.insert call near the end.

UPDATE: made correction as suggested by 2 posters of changing the >> to > >. No difference. Error persists.

Comment: You're going to have to share the error message.

Comment: Failing how, exactly? And which compiler do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `vertex` is a pointer. To access `getKey` you need to use `->` operator, not `.`. Plus, you can use `std::make_pair` to avoid repeating the types.

```
vertexes.insert(std::make_pair(vertex->getKey(), *vertex));
```

Comment: Bingo! Thank you very much. I assumed the problem was with vertexes because Visual Studio's Intellisense was failing to work properly on that variable. :\

Answer (score 1):

Not having the error message itself, I can't be that helpful. But if I may venture a guess:

Unless you are using C++0x,

```
std::map<KeyType, Vector<KeyType, ObjectType>> vertexes;
```

will fail parsing, since `>>` at the end is parsed as the operator, as opposed to the end of a nested template parameter list. So, you'll need to change that to

```
std::map<KeyType, Vector<KeyType, ObjectType> > vertexes;
```

This does get fixed in C++0x, though.

Comment: Hi Jonathan! Thanks for the reply. Said fix did not work. I just posted the error message in the original question.

Comment: Even though the other answer solved the problem, I think this observation will be useful to others in the future. Up-voted it!

Answer (score 0):

First change from Vector to Vertex (typo?). The second error is the "<<", if you put them together it will be the shift operator. Here is how that line should be:

```
std::map<KeyType, Vertex<KeyType, ObjectType> > vertexes;
```

**Edit:** With the new information I could spot another error:

In the method createVertex you are creating a new Vertex but using it as Value. For example, in this line:

```
vertexes.insert(std::pair<KeyType, Vertex<KeyType, ObjectType> >(vertex.getKey(), vertex));
```

The call:

```
vertex.getKey()
```

Vertex is a pointer, so you should change to vertex->getKey().
There are more errors, but all related to the fact that vertex is a pointer being treated as a value.

Comment: Hi felipe! Indeed the Vector was a typo. Made it while trying to fix the error this question is about. Corrected it. Added error message to question. Said fix of replacing shift operator did not work.